# jQuery: If class contains

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

`var testAnswer = $(this).attr("class");`

and then a check like so:

`if (testAnswer === "true") { /* some jazz */`

This works fine if I have `class="true"` but NOT if I have `class="true single-line"` presumably because I'm looking for an exact match instead of if it contains the word true in the class.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: One of the key features of jQuery is the reduced code. In most cases you wont need to use `if` statements to achieve things in jQuery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the jQuery [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) function.

```
if($(this).hasClass('true')) {
    /* some jazz */
}
```

Comment: 3 identical answers, +1 to the one with the lowest reputation score :)

Comment: What about checking if the variable has the class e.g. `if (testAnswer.hasClass("true"))` which doesn't seem to work??

Comment: @Cameron - testAnswer = $(this).attr("class") will set the className into this variable. You cannot call hasClass on it. You can instead use indexOf method in case you want to use that variable and dont want to change the code. Try if(testAnswer.indexOf("true") != -1){ }

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
if($(this).hasClass("true")){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var boolAnswer=$(this).hasClass('true');
```